# ArcGIS API - Cannot center or zoom

Tags: javascript, zooming, center, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

So, I am using the ARCGIS api in order to show some old maps, that should start center at and zoomed in to a certain city. After finally figuring out how to use the specific map I want as a basemap, I've struggled for a couple of hours trying to zoom and center at the right place. I am able to zoom in to this place using a default basemap (e.g. "streets"), but not using my custom basemap. I've tried both map.centerAndZoom and map.centerAt, but neither seem to work. The relevant code:

```
var map;
    require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", "dojo/on", "dojo/_base/json", "dojo/dom-style", "esri/request", "esri/geometry/Point", "esri/dijit/Search", "esri/dijit/LocateButton", "esri/tasks/GeometryService", "esri/tasks/locator", "esri/tasks/ProjectParameters", "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(Map, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer) {
        map = new Map("venster_Midden_2_Map");
        var customBasemap = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
        "http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/arcgis/rest/services/Historische_tijdreis_1815/MapServer");
        map.addLayer(customBasemap);
        map.centerAndZoom(51.1, 4.3, 0);
    });
```

Does anyone have a clue on how to get the zoom and center working? Or might it be the case that certain maps simply don't allow such operations?

Comment: I had troubles with all cases above & found solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121826/center-and-zoom-function-using-arcgis-api-for-javascript/366713#366713

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`centerAndZoom` is more intended for events, like when a user has chosen a certain city from a list and would like the map to automatically zoom to it. [As richj points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33585572/2118067), it also requires a point, and a zoom level of zero won't work.

If you don't want any of the Esri basemaps at all, just leave that out when initially creating the map. Slightly modifying [this Tiled Map Service sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_ags_tiled.html):

```
  require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(Map, Tiled) {
      map = new Map("map", {zoom: 3});

      var tiled = new Tiled("http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/arcgis/rest/services/Historische_tijdreis_1815/MapServer");
      map.addLayer(tiled);
    }
  );
```

Then, you will be able to include `centerAndZoom` as a *response to an event* (e.g. after the Tiled layer has been fully loaded from its web source).

```
  require(["esri/map",
           "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
           "esri/geometry/Point",
           "esri/SpatialReference",
           "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(Map, Tiled, Point, SpatRef) {
      map = new Map("map", {zoom: 3});

      var tiled = new Tiled("http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/arcgis/rest/services/Historische_tijdreis_1815/MapServer");
      map.addLayer(tiled);

      var cityCenter = new Point(121000, 495000, new SpatRef({ wkid: 28992 }));
      tiled.on("load",function(evt) {
        map.centerAndZoom(cityCenter, 6);
      });
    });
```

Ref. [`Point` constructor](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/point-amd.html#point1), [`centerAndZoom` method](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#centerandzoom), and [Working with events](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/inside_events.html).

Comment: Well, implementing your suggestion does allow me to zoom finally, so that's one thing. But unfortunately centering is still unresponsive. Whatever I enter for coordinates, it always ends up at the same place (somewhere in the middle of the map).
What puzzles me though is that the problem doesn't seem to be the map itself: i've tried other tiled services and all of them seem to have this problem. Other types of services seem to work fine though. Would it by chance be possible to load this map as another type of service? Maybe by 'converting' it manually? Or would that be an impossible task?

Comment: Trying to convert a tile map service is probably much, much harder than is worth your time :) Please see the edit; you can use an event listener to "watch" for when the tiled layer is finished loading and then trigger `centerAndZoom` that way. (Sorry I didn't think of that last night.)

Comment: Wow. Just when I had given up on solving this and instead had started on adding the map as simple graphics, you fixed it. I had actually already tried using a listener, but without success. Your usage of the correct spatref is probably what made it work. Thank you! Solved :)

Comment: I'm still not sure why using `center` in the initial map creation doesn't work, but this does work, so hurray!

Answer (score 0):

From the relevant [API documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#centerandzoom) the centreAndZoom method takes a Point as its first argument. Also your zoom factor of zero looks like it might cause a problem.

You might have more luck with a Point and a non-zero zoom scale, like this:

```
map.centerAndZoom(new Point(51.1, 4.3), 0.5);
```

The method has a Deferred return type so that you can provide a callback to react when the method call has completed.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. In fact, for some reason the only difference that exists is between when I don't add the line at all, and when I do add the line. It doesn't matter what the arguments would be in the second case though, whether I choose a zoom of 1 or 10. I think that the problem may rest in how the map is created in the first place. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I'm not getting anywhere with that map service layer. The spatial reference system is 28992 and the coordinates are not Long/Lat according to the [metadata](http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/arcgis/rest/services/Historische_tijdreis_1815/MapServer) but even with values that should be in range I just see the logo.

Comment: Exactly, but this seems to happen with whichever tiled map I load. Please see my reply to Erica for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is esri api bug, for me, it sometime (but not always) failed to move map center at lng, lat with zoom level 18

Here is how I work around:

Recommend:

`map.centerAndZoom(new Point(lng, lat), 18);`

Alternative: (sometimes, not always,  it failed to move the map, maybe ESRI need to fix bug for Javascript api v3.24)

```
map.centerAt(new Point(lng, lat));
//or
// map.centerAt(new Point(lng, lat, new SpatialReference({wkid: 4326})));
map.setZoom(18);
```